# how to load an image as a popup in kivy

Tags: android, python, kivy

```
def pop1(self):
    pop = Popup(title='test',content=Image('boy.png'),
                size_hint=(None,None))
    pop.open()
```

Then in the kv language i tried to call it from button on_press event.
the code for the kv file is this.

```
    BoxLayout:
    size:self.parent.size
    orientation:'horizontal'
    spacing:10
    padding:5
    Button:
        text:
        size_hint:.3,.3
        on_press: 
            root.pop1()
```

when i try to run it, i get an error as follows:

:
    _container: container
    GridLayout:
        padding: 12
keyError: 'pos_hint'

Answer (score 6):

First of all, since you call `root.pop1()` and `root` in this case is a `BoxLayout` I assume that you defined your `pop1` function in a class you called `BoxLayout` inheriting from `BoxLayout`? If so, you're basically overwriting a kivy class, which will mess things up.

A second issue is that you call `Image('boy.png')` when it should be `Image(source='boy.png')`.

Finally, in the button, you forgot to set `text` to a value.

A better way of doing what you're trying to accomplish is with the following code:

```
from kivy.app import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.lang import Builder


kv = '''
BoxLayoutWithPopup:
    orientation:'horizontal'
    spacing:10
    padding:5
    Button:
        text: 'Press me'
        size_hint:.3,.3
        on_press:
            root.pop1()
'''


class BoxLayoutWithPopup(BoxLayout):

    def pop1(self):
        pop = Popup(title='test', content=Image(source='boy.png'),
                    size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400))
        pop.open()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    runTouchApp(Builder.load_string(kv))
```

Comment: Thnx for the solution @Matt